# Inherited static methods not available in Java Nashorn

Tags: java, static-methods, nashorn

I've got a utility class that adds functionality to a more generic utility class. In Java everthing works as expected, but the behavior in Java's JavaScript engine Nashorn is different.

For clarification see the following code:

```
package com.test;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class Test {

    public static class A {
        public static void sayHello() {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public static void sayBye() {
            System.out.println("Goodbye cruel world");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Java's Behavior
        A.sayHello();    // Works
        B.sayBye();      // Works
        B.sayHello();    // Works

        // Java Nashorn's Behavior
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        engine.eval("var A = Java.type('com.test.Test.A')");
        engine.eval("var B = Java.type('com.test.Test.B')");

        engine.eval("A.sayHello()");    // Works
        engine.eval("B.sayBye()");      // Works
        engine.eval("B.sayHello()");    // Fails
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make `B.sayHello()` work with the Nashorn engine?

Comment: `B.sayHello()` shouldn't be used anyway. Classes are not objects.

Comment: @JimmyB Are you suggesting that static methods shouldn't be inherited? If so, I agree with you.

Comment: Ok, normally I would agree, but to give more context to my situation: e.g. there is a static method in the parent utility class `Utils#getDistance(PointF, PointF)` (utility class is used in multiple projects) and in the child I have a method `Utils#getDistance(Entity, Entity)` which will first retrieve the position from the entities and then return the distance. So I don't want to have a class `Utils` and `SpecificUtils` or whatever you call it then, with the same set of methods and only different parameters.

Comment: Just always call a static method on the class in which it is declared. You want to `sayHello`, you call`A.sayHello()`.

Comment: The point of using the scripting language in my case is to have an easy system that allows players to change some parts of the game. For this I want to keep it as simple as possible and don't want my players to have to search for the proper class in the API docs if the method is logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, static methods can be called only on the exact declaring class of the method (and not on it's subclasses). That is a design choice made to simplify dynalink linker (used by nashorn).